# python manage.py migrate: No module named 'muypicky.base'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Background: I'm taking a beginners Django course and I've run into an issue.  The following command isn't working in Terminal.

- Running on Mac
- Virtual environment
- Taking UDEMY Course: try-django-v1-11-python-web-development

**Command: python  manage.py migrate**

```
Terminal Output:
(trydjango1-11) C02T74CKGTF1:src josh.frazier$ python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/josh.frazier/Dev/trydjango1-11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/josh.frazier/Dev/trydjango1-11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 307, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/Users/josh.frazier/Dev/trydjango1-11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/josh.frazier/Dev/trydjango1-11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Users/josh.frazier/Dev/trydjango1-11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 110, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/Users/josh.frazier/Dev/trydjango1-11/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/josh.frazier/Dev/trydjango1-11/src/muypicky/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .base import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'muypicky.base'
```

Comment: also add your installed app configuration.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance!  How do I do that?

Comment: your error is not `command not found`, it is saying `no module muypicky.base`.

Comment: okay add your project setting also, if you are using different settings for local and production the what directory structure are you following and in that case add all the setting files.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wjTTcCTXBxB0OVUl6Dm7z3-clbgGh7Sd/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I added a zip file to my master file

Comment: Please show `muypicky/__init__.py`. There shouldn't be an `__init__` in your project root (the same directory as manage.py). I would try removing that file.

Comment: Thanks so much man!  First time on stack overflow and the question was answered in less than 30 minutes!  Awesome!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through your files, i found that you haven't imported local.py and production.py in your `__init__.py` add the following code to `__init__.py` file inside **settings** folder

```
from .base import *

from .production import *

try:
   from .local import *
except:
   pass
```